# migrating to git lfs by official guide creates bad object error

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs, bfg-repo-cleaner

Following [this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/migrate_to_git_lfs.html), when I get to the step `git push --force` I get the following error:

```sh
ref master:: Error in git rev-list --stdin --objects --not --remotes=origin --: exit status 128 fatal: bad object d096dd7506987ff3ede8754716b5fe076836b524
error: failed to push some refs to <git-url>
```

I have followed the guide exactly so am at a loss. Any suggestions welcome.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that [the upstream contains changes you don't have on your local copy of the remote](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3977) (in this case, the `d096dd7506987ff3ede8754716b5fe076836b524` commit).

Do a `git fetch` before pushing.

As you've mirrored the repo, you'll probably want to ensure that the commits on the remote that you don't have are properly merged in.